# Programmatically Converting Currency

Tags: programming, magento-1.5, currency

I am trying to convert currency in Magento 1.5 using the following code in a separate file to check currency conversion. I have two stores with respective currency settings in the admin.

```
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('D_S', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$_fromCurr = 'USD';
if( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode() == 'CAD') {
    $_locale = 'en_CA';
    $_toCurr = 'CAD';
} else {
    $_locale = 'en_US';
    $_toCurr = 'USD';
}
$currency = new Zend_Currency($_locale); 
$amount = 150;
echo $_price = $currency->toCurrency(round( Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert( $amount, $_fromCurr, $_toCurr ), 2 ));
```

I am getting following error,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/www.test.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php on line 171

I tried following this http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/118631/P15/#t381027, but it does not work. What is wrong here?

Comment: you can only use this function to convert currency `round( Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert( $amount, $_fromCurr, $_toCurr ), 2 )`

Comment: @Dinesh - Are there still unanswered questions here, or does my answer below get you where you need to be? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Did @davidalger's answer help you? If so, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP fatal error is stemming from a bug in the convert method where it assumes that $toCurrency is an object. The error, however, is being caused when it's trying to throw an exception:

```
throw new Exception(Mage::helper('directory')->__('Undefined rate from "%s-%s".', $this->getCode(), $toCurrency->getCode()));
```

The meaning of this error is that the `convert` method cannot find a rate. I tested your code, and it works fine, as long as the rates exist for the currencies you are converting to/from.

What you'll need to do is navigate to System -> Configuration -> Currency Setup and make sure the currencies you are using are selected in the Allowed Currencies setting.

After you have selected the Allowed Currencies, you'll need to set the rates. You can do this by going to System -> Manage Currency Rates. From there you can either input your own conversion ratios into the grid or import them by clicking the Import button, then click Save Currency Rates.

Once you have the currency rates for the conversion setup, it should work without a hitch.

Comment: Wouldn't Magento have used `Mage::throwException` here?

Comment: `Mage::throwException` is only used where a `Mage_Core_Exception` is needed, the exception class which is frequently caught and used for user error messaging or added as an error message by passing true as a 2nd param.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will worked

```
$_Baseprice = $_product->getPrice(); 
    $_Currentcurrencycode =Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    //This will return USD, EUR e.t.c
    //echo $_Currentcurrencycode;
    if ($_Currentcurrencycode == 'USD') {$_convertedCurrency = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($cprice, 'SAR', 'USD');}
    else {$_convertedCurrency = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($cprice, 'SAR', 'SAR');}
    //_convertedCurrency will return price without symbol
    //echo $_convertedCurrency ;
```