# Get Magento quote totals in base currency

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, currency

***[[Cross-posted from StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685350/get-magento-quote-totals-in-base-currency)***

Is there a way to get the quote/cart totals in the base currency from a Mage_Sales_Model_Quote object?

Ideally something like getTotals() but with the base currency instead of the user's selected currency.

This is a single store, multiple currencies site.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** example code for what I've tried -

```
// value - 1917.47
$value = $observer->getEvent()->getCart()->getQuote()->getTotals()['grand_total']; 

// localCurr - "EUR"
$localCurr = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 

// baseCurr - "GBP"
$baseCurr = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 

Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($value, $localCurr, $baseCurr);
```

This results in an error like

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in <..>\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php on line 194
```

**Edit 2:** I saw this which seems to generate the same kind of error, but my currencies do exist in the backend

[Programmatically Converting Currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/programmatically-converting-currency)

**Edit 3:** I don't feel this is a duplicate of the above question because that's just relevant to a solution I tried. The initial problem I have is different, I'm looking for the best solution to that. Converting the currency back is just a (somewhat kludgey) solution I tried.

Comment: Note that there is indeed an issue when the currency conversion is the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**When dealing with converting a non base currency to the base currency**

There is an issue when converting from GBP (which is not the base currency) to EUR (the base currency) this happens when saving/reading the rates from the database table `directory_currency_rate`. Magento will only save the base currencies set-up via the config under the currency_from column.

One thing you could look into is how `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Webservicex` and the _convert function works.

```
protected function _convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, $retry=0)
{
    $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', $currencyFrom, $this->_url);
    $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_TO}}', $currencyTo, $url);

    try {
        $response = $this->_httpClient
            ->setUri($url)
            ->setConfig(array('timeout' => Mage::getStoreConfig('currency/webservicex/timeout')))
            ->request('GET')
            ->getBody();

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response, null, LIBXML_NOERROR);
        if( !$xml ) {
            $this->_messages[] = Mage::helper('directory')->__('Cannot retrieve rate from %s.', $url);
            return null;
        }
        return (float) $xml;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        if( $retry == 0 ) {
            $this->_convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, 1);
        } else {
            $this->_messages[] = Mage::helper('directory')->__('Cannot retrieve rate from %s.', $url);
        }
    }
}
```

You could try something similar and get the conversion rate on the fly when you need it. This is not an ideal solution but you could also save these conversion rates into the table after the original rates are saved using an after save events.

**When dealing with base currency to another currency conversion**

Makes sure that you have imported all the currency rates via the admin section.

Under System->Manage Currency->Rates you are able to import the currency rates from webservicex.

Once this is complete you should be able to convert from your base currency to that of any currency you have the rate for.

If you need more currencies they can be setup via System->Config->Currency Setup but after that you will need to reimport the new currency rates.

Comment: That's the problem, these currencies do exist in the back-end. The only thing I can imagine is that converting in reverse (which is what I'm trying to do here) doesn't work unless in import the reverse rates perhaps? 

If that's the case I feel like there has to be a better solution to my initial problem

Comment: @9point6 sorry I did not notice that the currencies convert was the other way around.

Comment: No worries, Thanks for the solution posted. Is this the way you'd recommend I go about solving my initial problem then? I feel like this has gotten to be quite hacky for something I thought would have quite a simple solution. (Sorry - I'm quite new to Magento development!)

Comment: I would suggest going down the event route and saving the rates yourself, either that or you would need to create a website for each of your currencies :(

Comment: Okay then, fair enough. Thanks for your help